# Hibernate Row Locking on read

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, transactions

I have a table `Jobs` with fields `Name` and `Status`.

I'm trying to deploy two separate applications in a tomcat instance to poll the jobs table for new records but it's important that the same job record is not received by both processes. How can I do this?

My (unsuccessful) approach thus far has been to use spring integration:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter 
    query="select * from jobs where status=1"
    channel="rawInputDataListChannel"
    data-source="dataSource"
    update="update input_table set status=2 where status=1">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1">
        <int:transactional isolation="READ_COMMITTED" />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Since this didn't work I thought that maybe having the transaction manager in tomcat so it could be shared by both applications might work but I'm struggling to get that up and running. Would this approach work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the title of your question mentions hibernate so lets look at what JPA 2.0 has to offer which is around the idea of `LockMode` and pessimistic locking.  in the case you're looking at, you want to run queries, possibly simultaneously, and have each JVM get a unique set of results.  that being the case, you want to emulate a `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` (which is kinda proprietary and dependant on your database as to whether or not it will directly support that statement).

in JPA 2.0 you can use `@LockMode` and specify that the resultset is retrieve with the intention of updating, so 'lock' it at the database so no other connection can get the same results.

have a look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212234526/https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/jpa_2_0_concurrency_and) article to try and explain it better than i, and have a look particularly at the 'pessimistic' patterns.

edit >>>

if you're looking at hibernate 3.x, try [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html) link

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I was wrong in thinking I was depending on hibernate in the SI example in my post - it was simply SQL using the datasource. I added 'FOR UPDATE' and it worked perfectly. Thankyou!